# C++ find size of the short* array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Not very familiar with C++, and have perhaps some very fundamental question:

i have a struct:

```
struct ADDING_BYVAL
{
    #define THIRDNUMBER 100;

    short _firstNBuff[4];
    long _secondNVal;
    short* _thirdNBuff;
    char* _pretext;
};
```

I am initializing this struct as so:

```
short thirdBuff[] = {6, 7};
char pret1[] = { "pretextVal" };
struct ADDING_BYVAL adding_byval = { 
    { 1,2,3,4 }, 
    5, 
    thirdBuff,
    pret1
};
```

now I want to find the length of the array `adding_byval._thirdNBuff` using sizeof() gives me size of the pointer rather than size of the array it points to.  How do i do that?

Comment: `adding_byval._thirdNBuff` *Is*  a pointer, not an array.

Comment: You can't get the size of an array through a pointer, and you also can't know in general what a pointer is pointing to, if anything. Store and track the length separately or use a more self-explanatory type like `std::vector<short>` or `std::span<short>`

Comment: The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself. The compiler doesn't know what it might point to.

Comment: `std::array<short,4> _firstNBuff{1,2,3,4};` and then `_firstNBuff.size()`. This is C++ just forget "C" style arrays ever existed. If you need a pointer to the array's data just use `values.data()` For the dynamically sized arrays (_thirdNBuff) use `std::vector<short>` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: see also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay and then here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: Pointers are really simple. All they know is where they point. They don't know if there is anything at the address they store. If there is anything, they don't know how big it is. That simplicity brings efficiency, but you have to be careful with them.

Comment: @user4581301 Which also means pointers are too simple to model arrays correctly... all size information is lost. Which is an endless source of bugs.